# Mocking a LDAP Server in Python (ldap3)

Tags: python, mocking, ldap, ldap3

I am currently trying to mock the LDAP server we are using in the company. For connections to it in our web app we use python ldap3, so I decided to use the mocking feature of ldap3 (which is documented here: https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/mocking.html). However, it can't seem to work for some reason and the resources online on this topic are scarce.

This is my current code:

```
//imports and environment variables for the LDAP servers

...

_LDAP_SERVER = Server(host=LDAP.host, port=int(LDAP.port), get_info='ALL')

    server = _LDAP_SERVER

    #connection to real server
_CONNECTION = Connection(
    server,
    LDAP.manager_dn, LDAP.manager_password,
    auto_bind=True, client_strategy=RESTARTABLE
)

#extracting the json files
server.info.to_file('my_real_server_info.json')
server.schema.to_file('my_real_server_schema.json')

#getting the real server entries - everything works to this point
if _CONNECTION.search(LDAP.root_dn, _ALL_USERS_SEARCH_FILTER, attributes=_SEARCH_ATTRIBUTES):
    _CONNECTION.response_to_file('my_real_server_entries.json', raw=True)

_CONNECTION.unbind()

#creating the mock server per guidelines
mock_server = Server.from_definition('Mock Server', 'my_real_server_info.json', 'my_real_server_schema.json')

#making a new fake connection
fake_connection = Connection(mock_server, user='CN=testuser, CN=users, DC=company, DC=com', password='fakepassword',
                             client_strategy=MOCK_SYNC)


fake_connection.strategy.add_entry('CN=selen001,CN=users, DC=company,DC=com', {

                        "cn": "selen001", #username
                        "displayName": "Admin, selenium",
                        "mail": "selenium@COMPANY.COM",

                    }
                )

fake_connection.strategy.add_entry('CN=selen002,CN=users,DC=company,DC=int', {

                        "cn": "selen002", #username
                        "displayName": "User, selenium",
                        "mail": "selenium2@COMPANY.COM",

                        }
                    )

fake_connection.bind()

#I want to test if it works, but I can't get any results
if fake_connection.search('DC=company,DC=com', _ALL_USERS_SEARCH_FILTER, attributes=_SEARCH_ATTRIBUTES):
    fake_connection.response_to_file('my_real_server_entries1337.json', raw=True)
```

So to summarise: (1) Connection to Real Server, (2) get its schema and info, (3) generate its entities, (4) create a mock server and a fake connection with fake user, (5) add fake users, (6) test if it works (I can't get a result out of this, which leads me to think that there is an error somewhere, even though I followed the code closely..).

Thank you.